# POST request from iphone to wcf service?

Tags: objective-c, wcf, http-post

I m doing the concept of sending(POST) XML request from iPhone to wcf service and I knew the phenomenon of sending a XML request.But I have html data which I retrieved from wcf service and I have to POST the same data as request to service.After retrieving the html data I m storing it in  NSString variable and passed that string in request.But Im not able to POST and getting error . 'There was an error deserializing the object of type EService.svc. The token '[CDATA[' was expected but found 'DOCTYPE'.Why I m getting this error?

Html response from service is like this :

```
(
        {
        BodyEmailforResult = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
\n<head>
\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />
\n<title>Untitled Document</title>
\n</head>
\n
\n<body style=\"background:#bdd9ef; padding:20px 0px; margin:0px;\">
\n\t<table width=\"700px\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" style=\"border-radius:10px; margin:0px auto; background:white; color:#2222; padding:20px 0px;\" >
\n
\n    <tr>
\n    \t<td style=\"height:130px; background:#e8e8e8; border-bottom:2px solid #c5c5c5; margin:0px; \" >
\n        \t<table width=\"100%\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">
\n            \t<tr>
\n                \t<td width=\"40%\" style=\"padding-left:20px;\" >
\n\t\t        \t\t<img src=\"http://123.32.34.45/images/logo.png\"  />
\n                    </td>
\n                    <td>
\n                    \t<p style=\"color:#1b1b1b; margin:0px; font-size:14px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:20px; text-align:right; padding-right:20px; \" >Visit  website</p>
\n                        <p style=\"color:#0459df; margin:0px; font-size:14px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:20px; text-align:right; padding-right:20px; text-decoration:underline; \"><a href=\"http://123.32.34.45\" style=\"color:#0459df; font-weight:bold; \" >123.32.34.45</a></p>
\n                    </td>
\n               </tr>
\n        \t</table>
\n        </td>
\n        
\n    </tr>
\n    <tr>
\n    \t<td height=\"20px\" >
\n        
\n        </td>
\n    </tr>
\n\t<tr>
\n    \t<td style=\"color:#1b1b1b; font-size:14px; text-align:left; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:24px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; \" >
\n        \t<p style=\"margin:0px; line-height:30px; \" >Dear <span style=\"font-weight:bold;\" >Mary</span></p>
\n            
\n            
\n            <p style=\"margin:0px; line-height:24px; padding-top:10px; \" >
\n            \tThis is to confirm that we have received your registration request for your Account. We have created a temporary link listed below. You can use this link to activate your user account. 
\n            </p>
\n                        
\n            <p style=\"margin:0px; padding-top:10px; \" >You can <a href=\"123.32.34.45/Verify.aspx?Code=N6zDZK \" style=\"color:#0459df; font-weight:bold;\" >click hear </a> to activate your user account. </p>
\n            
\n            <p style=\"margin:0px; padding-top:10px;\" >Once you confirm your e-mail account, away to make. Note that use your e-mail and password to sign-in.
\n
\n</p>
\n<p style=\"margin:0px; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:10px;\" >Registration Details :</p>
\n<p style=\"margin:0px; padding-top:10px;\" >Your registration successfully completed Thanks for your registration</p>
\n
\n
\n<p style=\"margin:0px; font-size:16px; padding-top:30px;\" >
\nThanks & Regards
\n</p>
\n<p style=\"color:#0080b8; margin:0px; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:10px;\" >
\n
\n</p>
\n
\n
\n        </td>
\n    </tr>
\n    </table>
\n    
\n</body>
\n</html>";
    }
)

I took this response in string as :
 NSString *bodyofemail=[[arr2 objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"BodyEmailforResult"];

and POST request is like this :

    NSString *url5=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://123.32.34.45/EService.svc/SendEmail"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request5=[[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]autorelease];
        [request5 setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url5]];
        [request5 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *contentType5=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"text/xml"];
        [request5 addValue:contentType5 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        NSMutableData *postBody5=[NSMutableData data];
        [postBody5 appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<EmailServiceRequest xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody5 appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Body>%@</Body>",bodyofemail]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody5 appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<FromEmail>glory@i.net</FromEmail>"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody5 appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Subject>%@</Subject>",subjectofemail]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody5 appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<ToEmail>%@</ToEmail>",txtemail.text]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody5 appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</EmailServiceRequest>>"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request5 setHTTPBody:postBody5];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse5=nil;
    NSError *error5=nil;
    NSData *responseData5 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request5
                                                  returningResponse:&urlResponse5
                                                              error:&error5];

    if (responseData5!= NULL)
    {
        NSString *rss5 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData5
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
        NSLog(@"Response Code:%d",[urlResponse5 statusCode]);
        if([urlResponse5 statusCode ]>=200 && [urlResponse5 statusCode]<300)
        {
            NSLog(@"Response:%@",rss5);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to send request: %@", [error5 localizedDescription]);
    }
```

But I got error like this:'There was an error deserializing the object of type EService.svc. The token '[CDATA[' was expected but found 'DOCTYPE'.

Where I m going wrong and how to POST html data to wcf service ?

Any help would be appeciated..

Answer (score 0):

A WCF service usually requires requests to be [*soap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) requests unless the service has been configured to use `WebHttpBinding` which allows either XML or JSON requests. You should find out from the service developers whether the service accepts only soap XML or if it can accept plain XML or JSON.

In either case, the easiest way to tackle this kind of problem is to capture the XML requests (soap or not) from a successful call (from another service client) and use those messages as a template for the XML (or JSON) string you need to build in your iOS app.